# How do I call a function located in another file in C using external?

Tags: c

I'm using a book, and now I'm studying external variables. I'm supposed to use a function located in another file and return a value from that function. But I don't understand how does this happens exactly. This is the code provided by the book:

This is the code in the first file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
double getCircum(double);


double PI = 3.14;
int gi;

int main(void)
{

double r = 5.87;
const double PI = 3.14;

printf("%.f", getCircum(r));

}
```

This is the code in the other file:

```
external double PI;

double getCircum(double r)
{

return 2 * r * PI;
}
```

The output is supposed to be 36.88. but I keep getting an error message that the file is not the directory. I don't know what file it that. Also, I don't really get how the code is supposed to look for a function in a different file, is the code missing something?

Comment: What's printing the error message?  How are you compiling your code?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I just run the code in the first file.

Comment: What is the build command (gcc ...) ? what is the exact error message. Please post to question, if possible

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `double PI = 3.14` should have a semicolon after it.

Comment: The missing semi-colon makes as much sense as "external", somebody will have to talk the OP off that ledge.  Big job.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible through to the linking process.

When reading your C *first file*, the compiler will output an **object file** which contain unresolved *references* to symbols like `printf`, `getCircum` because they are **declared** (*printf* in `<stdio.h>` and *getCircum* in your first file) but **not implemented** (you didn't wrote them code in the first file).
When reading the *second file*, the compiler will miss the definition of `PI`.

This doesn't prevent him from producing valid object files. After removing the line `double PI = 3.14` (it miss a `;`), compile without linking with :

```
cc -c -o 1st_file.o 1st_file.c
cc -c -o 2nd_file.o 2nd_file.c
```

This will output two *object files*, if you run `obj-dump -t 1st_file.o 2st_file.o` you will see a list of *provided* and *unresolved* symbols of both files.

Now we will **link** with `cc -o program.exe 1st_file.o 2nd_file.o`. The C compiler will link both objects and some system-wide ones inside `program.exe`.

In your case `cc -o program.exe 1st_file.c 2nd_file.c` will do the job. But in real program, recompiling the whole program at each test take a lot of time, I have a private project which take 3,5 seconds to link vs 17,5 to recompile everything for 4k lines of code, Linux itself has more than a 2M lines of code...

My answer make the important assumption that you are on a Linux with a working C compiler and GNU binutils.

*Edit: Defining PI 2 times here is not an error*

Comment: `...and you define PI two time, these are errors...`: no. One definition is at file scope, the other is in the scope of `main`. If the missing semicolon at the end of `double PI = 3.14` is added it compiles just fine. And if you change the initialization of the `PI` defined in `main` to something ridiculous you'll see that only the file-scope `PI` is used.